# Get the response code or return value of server if I used the html form (not ajax)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm using the following web technologies for my web application:
HTML JS, CSS and appweb server.

I'm creating a login page. I have a form of course and the value of username and password is sent using jquery post. If the username and password of the user is correct, the server side code will redirect the user to the landing page, let's say "/MyPage.html". If the input is invalid, server will send a json format data that looks something like this :

> {"error":"Invalid username or password"}

This wouldnt work because according to the support of the server that I'm using, **"browser wont redirect based based on a 301/302 to ajax request."**

So I have no choice but to use the html submit form.
This is my login form removing all css.

```
<form action="/usr/login" method="post">
username: <input type="text" name="username" "><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password" ><br>
<button>Sign in</button>
</form>
```

This is the jquery code for those who wants to see it.

```
$.ajax({ 
   url:"/user/login", 
   type:"POST", 
   data: { 
      username : document.getElementById("username").value,     
      password : document.getElementById("password").value  
   }, 
   error:function(xhr, status){     
      if (xhr.status == "401") { 
         document.getElementById("invalid").innerHTML='<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Invalid ID or password.</div>';     
         document.getElementById("password").value = "";    
      }else if (xhr.status == "404") {      
         document.getElementById("invalid").innerHTML='<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Page not found.</div>';     
         document.getElementById("password").value = "";    
      }else{        
         document.getElementById("invalid").innerHTML="";   
      }  
  } 
});
```

1) How am I going to know (client side) if the inputs are invalid without using ajax?
2) Is it possible to get the response code of the server considering the limitations? how?

Comment: Can you write the code where you are using the jQuery post to send the data to server as I think you can modify the code to handle error ?

Comment: Hi @RaghvendraKumar I added the jquery code to my post. Kindly check it out, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you know the exact message that you will get from the server, you can extract it from the json string that you get from server and do a normal comparison to check it.

```
   error:function(xhr, status)
         {     
           var json    = xhr.responseText;
           var jsonObj = JSON.parse(json);
           var msg     = jsonObj.error;  

             if (msg == "Invalid username or password") 
             {  
                 // your code to set the innerHTML or javascript to perform redirection
             }
         }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This would work. but, when we're talking about web application, is it okay or normal or best practice that the client will be the one to have the redirection code?

Comment: Not sure if it's best practice or not, but I think you mentioned in the question that  you don't have much choice with the server or server side code, if I got you correct. If you can't perform server side redirection,  because of server's limitation then you can think of a server side forward by checking for the same error on server side if found or a javascript redirection, also it's not entirely unsafe as it's a post request.